# React Native Community DateTimePicker value.getTime is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs, datetimepicker

Hey guys I have few questions regarding the community version of the RN DateTimePicker (https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#value-required)

First of all my Code:

State:

```
activityDate: todaysDate, (just a JS new Date())
showDatePicker: false
```

Toggle Function:

```
  showDatePickerHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      showDatePicker: !this.state.showDatePicker
    })
  }
```

DateTimePicker Code:

```
   <Button onPress={this.showDatePickerHandler} title="Open"/>
    <>
    { this.state.showDatePicker && (
    <DateTimePicker 
      // style={{width: "60%"}}
      value={this.state.activityDate}
      placeholderText="Pick your Date"
      onChange={(event, date) => {
        this.resetSOFT()             
        this.setState({ 
          // activityDate: date,
          activityDate: Moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          checked: false,
         }
        )  
      }}
    />
    )}
    </>
```

Here is what I am experiencing:

- When I open the DatePicker and then chose a date and press Ok (or cancel) my App reloads with this error: **TypeError: value.getTime is not a function. (In 'value.getTime()', 'value.getTime' is undefined)** - value is set to new Date() so thats weird
- is there a way to set a Format to the whole DateTimePicker Component? something like `format = "YYYY-MM-DD"` and then it should use this format for the date

I was using: https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker before which had some good formating functions and an easy way to handle dates - but since its buggy on IOS and has no maintainer I wanted to switch..

Edit:
On my first Press it looks good I am getting a Date but when I open it again it crashes the app and reloads it.. how can I safely close the Picker? is it enought to setState of showDatePicker to false in the onChange?

Answer (score 0):

You can only set a `new Date()` type as the `value` of `DateTimePicker` component.

You can show the date in required format in another component like below.

```
  <>
    {this.state.showDatePicker && (
      <DateTimePicker 
        style={{height: 0}}
        value={this.state.activityDate}
        placeholderText="Pick your Date"
        onChange={(event, date) => {
          this.resetSOFT()             
          this.setState({ 
            activityDate: date,
            checked: false,
            showDatePicker: false
          })  
       }}
      />
    )}
    <TouchableOpacity style={{padding:20, width:'80%', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}} onPress={()=>showDatePickerHandler()}>
      <Text>{Moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </>
```

Comment: When I change it I get: Invariant Violation: A date or time should be specified as `value`. Also I really want or need a Format.

Comment: look at the updated answer, you wrote like that right? you can show the formatted date like passed as title of button or you can pass any where like that

Comment: Pressing the Picker the first time looks good even when I format the date, the second press crashes the Picker - do you know how to close it safely? setting the showDatePicker state to false does it but it also reloads.

Comment: Try updated code with picker component invisible by giving height as 0 then use text component wrapped by TouchableOpacity component to show the formatted date. so you can handle onPress of the date wrapper to show DateTimePicker and in onChange of DateTimePicker make the flag as false

Answer (score 0):

replace `Value.getTime` by `Date.perse(value)` in node_Modules in
node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/src at

1.DatatimePicker.android.js line No:88,

2.DatatimePicker.ios.js line No:69